# How can I fix my Duplicate Children error?

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx, imageview, parent-child

I am having some trouble with my code currently. I have a button that is supposed to loop through an ImageView array list I have created and display 4 cards everytime it is pressed. Right now I can get my "Play" button to work, it's main function is to just display the cards 1 time and then be disabled. The "Deal" button is supposed to display 4 random cards every time I press it, until all of the cards are gone. Right now I can get it to change 1 card 1 time and then I get a "Duplicate Children" error. I know that the issue has to do with looping through the same border panes each time, but I was hoping for some advice on a good way to fix this issue. I know it might involve changing my code around a good bit and that's okay. Thank you!

```
        import java.io.File;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import javafx.scene.image.Image;
        import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
        import java.util.Collections;
        import java.util.EnumSet;
        import java.util.List;
        import javafx.application.Application;
        import javafx.event.*;
        import javafx.scene.Scene;
        import javafx.scene.control.Button;
        import javafx.stage.Stage;
        import javafx.scene.layout.*;
        import javafx.scene.control.Label;
        import javafx.geometry.*;
        import java.util.*;

        import javafx.scene.Node;
        import javafx.scene.image.Image;
        import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
        import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

        import javax.swing.*;

public class War extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    List<Integer> deck;
    ArrayList<ImageView> imager = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
    private int roundCounter;
    JButton button = new JButton();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        loadDeck();
        loadCards();
        //Panes
        BorderPane bPain = new BorderPane();
        VBox vBox = new VBox(100);
        vBox.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        HBox buttonBox = new HBox(100);
        buttonBox.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 75));
        buttonBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue");


        BorderPane bPain4 = new BorderPane();
        bPain.setLeft(new P1Pane("PLayer 1"));
        bPain4.setRight(new P2Pane("PLayer 2"));
        BorderPane bPain2 = new BorderPane();
        bPain2.setRight(new P3Pane("PLayer 4"));
        bPain2.setLeft(new P4Pane("PLayer 3"));




        BorderPane bPain3 = new BorderPane();
        DeckPane dPane = new DeckPane("Deck");


        bPain3.setCenter(dPane);
        bPain3.setMargin(dPane, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        bPain3.setCenter(dPane);

        //Buttons
        Button pBtn = new Button("PLAY");
        Button dBtn = new Button("DEAL");
        Button endBtn = new Button("END GAME");
        buttonBox.getChildren().addAll(pBtn, dBtn , endBtn);


        vBox.getChildren().addAll(buttonBox, bPain, bPain3, bPain2, bPain4);


        pBtn.setOnAction(
                p -> {System.out.println("Play pressed");
                loadCards();

            });
        pBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {


            public void handle(ActionEvent p) {
                bPain.getChildren().add(imager.get(10));
                bPain4.getChildren().add(imager.get(20));
                bPain2.getChildren().add(imager.get(30));
                bPain3.getChildren().add(imager.get(40));
            }
        });


        dBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {


            public void handle(ActionEvent d) {
                for(int i = 0; i<deck.size(); i++){
                //bPain2.getChildren().add(imager.get(i));
                //bPain4.getChildren().add(imager.get(i));
                bPain.getChildren().add(imager.get(i));
                //bPain3.getChildren().add(imager.get(i));
                }
            }
        });

        endBtn.setOnAction(
                e -> {
                    //when pressed, popup asks if sure
                    //disabled after
                    //resets number of wins
                    System.out.println("End pressed");
                });



        //Stage set
        primaryStage.setTitle("WAR!!!");
        //primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vBox2, 100, 100));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vBox, 500, 500));

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void loadCards() {

        String path = "/users/ebrovski/Desktop/card";
        String files;
        File folder = new File(path);
        Image[] images = new Image[100];
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            if (listOfFiles[i].getName().endsWith("png")) {
                System.out.println(listOfFiles[i].getAbsolutePath());

                files = "file:" + listOfFiles[i].getAbsolutePath();
                System.out.println(files);

                images[j] = new Image(files, 200, 200, true, true);

                j++;
            }
        }

        for(int k = 0; k < deck.size(); k++) {
            imager.add(new ImageView(images[deck.get(k)]));

        }
    }



    public void loadDeck() {
        deck = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i =0; i < 52; i++) {
            deck.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(deck);
    }


    //Player Panes
    class P1Pane extends Pane {

        private void add(ImageView get) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
        public P1Pane(String player) {
            Label playerTitle = new Label(player);
            getChildren().add(playerTitle);
            setStyle("-fx-border-color: black");
            //setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
            setPadding(new Insets(75, 1, 1, 1));

           // getChildren().add(imager.get(10));

        }
    }

    class P2Pane extends Pane {
        public P2Pane(String player) {
            Label playerTitle = new Label(player);
            getChildren().add(playerTitle);
            setStyle("-fx-border-color: black");
            //setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
            setPadding(new Insets(75, 1, 1, 1));
            //getChildren().add(imager.get(20));
        }
    }
    class P3Pane extends Pane {
        public P3Pane(String player) {
            Label playerTitle = new Label(player);
            getChildren().add(playerTitle);
            setStyle("-fx-border-color: black");
            //setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
            setPadding(new Insets(75, 3, 3, 3));
            //getChildren().add(imager.get(40));

        }
    }

    class P4Pane extends Pane {
        public P4Pane(String player) {
            Label playerTitle = new Label(player);
            getChildren().add(playerTitle);
            setStyle("-fx-border-color: black");
            //setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
            setPadding(new Insets(75, 3, 3, 3));
            //getChildren().add(imager.get(30));
        }
    }


    //Deck Pane
    class DeckPane extends Pane {
        public DeckPane(String deckName) {
            Label deckTitle = new Label(deckName);
            getChildren().add(deckTitle);

            setStyle("-fx-border-color: black");
            //setStyle("-fx-background-color: forestgreen");
            setPadding(new Insets(75, 3, 3, 3));

        }
    }


}
```

Now that I am on my work computer, I am getting a different error having to do with my loadDeck(); method. Here is the run-time error:
Please help!

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:303)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:875)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(LauncherImpl.java:157)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$49/28230490.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100
    at war.War.loadCards(War.java:151)
    at war.War.start(War.java:50)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(LauncherImpl.java:821)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$64/26176767.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/11567059.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/14442382.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/30452001.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$38/2075313.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Note on coding style: I find your naming to be quite awkward; why call something `bPain` - when something like `centralPane` would actually tell you what the thing is for? Meaning: your "pre fixes", like "b" and "v"; then mixed with "postfixes" like "Btn" or "Pain" ... are more confusing than helping.

Comment: thank you for the tip! Do you have any advice about the error I'm having? @Jägermeister

Comment: Stacktrace with the error would help.

Comment: Ah yes good point! @user979349 . So I could create a Stacktrace and then how would I add the images to it?

Comment: I mean post your exception stack trace here.

Comment: No need for images, just post the full error message including the stack trace that you get when the exception is thrown.

Comment: posted error that I am currently getting @NateBarbettini

Answer (score 0):

With e. g. bPain.getChildren().add(imager.get(i)); you add an ImageView to bPain. Next time the action is invoked you add the same ImageView again, although it's already on the Scene.

You must add children only once to the Scene.

And the error

Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100

you just posted is because you limited Image[] images = new Image[100];

Either stop adding items to the array after the size limit is reached or use an ArrayList.

Comment: right this makes sense. How can I add a different image view to the panes every time?

Comment: I have no idea what you wish to achieve. If you want to just use a random image, load the images into an ArrayList, invoke shuffle() on it and every time you want to use an image of the list remove the image from the list.

Comment: I am trying to get my button to display 4 random images from the deck I have created every time I click. There are 52 cards in the file so this would essentially be 12 times, because the play button displays the first 4. So I would shuffle and remove 4 cards inside my event handler?

Comment: And in regards to my error I posted above, I changed                       Image[] images = new Image[200]; and stopped getting it. Now I'm back to the duplicate children error.

Comment: Use List<Image> images = new ArrayList<Images> instead of an array. And yes, just remove the one you use from the list.

Comment: I'm getting an incompatible type error when trying to use an array list instead of an array. Do I need to change the way I'm looping through the images as well to fix this?